# Thread Status in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I tried looking for a thread on this subject, however couldn't find one. So posting this question.

Assume, I have created couple of threads in C++ in Linux and the code is running.

Now I would like to monitor the process and the threads of the process using a shell script and do some additional processing.

Also I would need the amount of CPU and Memory being used by each thread. I know that a thread is associated to a process, however my requirement is to identify the resources utilized by this thread.

I couldn't find the exact way to identify the threads associated to a process. I tried using PS however I couldn't find any clues. Running RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

From a man page of `ps`:

```
   To get info about threads:
      ps -eLf
      ps axms
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for `ps` might give you more clues.

In particular, it should tell you that `-L` shows threads, and `-o %cpu,%mem` will display the amount of CPU and memory being used.

Note that memory is associated with the process, not with any thread, so there is no concept of "memory used by each thread".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Linux commands you can use [Generic Memory Manager](http://memory-mgr.sourceforge.net/) library. Here it defined ThreadingModel class.